# Layout error due to ListView and PageView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKeyProfilePage,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: user == null
      ? Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
      : RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: _onRefresh,
          child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
               
                  children: [
                    BuildMainProfile(
           ....//build profile (with heiht = ScreenHeight/1.4)
          ),
                   
                    Container(
                   ...//to build bio section 
                    ),
                 
                    Flexible(
                            child: PageView(
            
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                            
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: 30,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Container(color: index%2==0?Colors.red:Colors.green,height: 30.0,width: double.infinity,),
                          );
                         },
                        ),
           Container(height: 400,width: 200,color: Colors.green,),
            Container(height: 400,width: 200,color: Colors.blue,),
             Container(height: 400,width: 200,color: Colors.pink,)
            ],
                  ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
        ),
        ),
    );
```

I am getting an error saying :

> The ParentDataWidget Flexible(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of
> type FlexParentData to a I/flutter ( 9926): RenderObject, which has
> been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.
> I/flutter ( 9926): Usually, this means that the Flexible widget has
> the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, I/flutter ( 9926):
> Flexible widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets. I/flutter (
> 9926): The offending Flexible is currently placed inside a
> RepaintBoundary widget. 
> .
> .
> .
> .
>  Another exception was
> thrown: Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height. I/flutter (
> 9926): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderViewport#4dd2b NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE I/flutter ( 9926): Another exception was
> thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#4dd2b NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

How can this error be removed, I have even used Flexible over PageView and shrinkWrap in listView.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly use `Flexible` in `ListView`. Maybe you must try something like this

```
return DefaultTabController(
  length: 3,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(Translator.of(context).translate("ratingsandreviews"),),
      bottom: TabBar(
        indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(),
        tabs: <Widget>[
          Tab(child: Icon(Icons.grid_on_outlined),),
          Tab(child: Icon(Icons.timeline),),
          Tab(child: Icon(Icons.account_box),),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    body: TabBarView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListView(
          children: [
            BuildMainProfile(),
            Container(
              //to build bio section 
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: POSTLIST.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(); // or what you want
                },
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SecondPage(), // second page
        ThirdPage(), // third page
        Fourth(), // fourth page
        // RideSharingReviewsPage(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hey!! thanks the solution is working, something I forget to mention in my question was my first child of PageView would actually be having a list view builder. So I can't constrain the height of my PageView. The layout is very much similar to an Instagram profile page, where PageView here is used to seeing the users post. So any idea how can that be done.

Comment: Has your primary question been answered ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. But next time avoid doing that. If your first question is answered and you have another one, then post another question

Comment: Sure I would take care onwards. Coming to the question, with the updated method the list will be able to scroll in just that constraint of 400, that is something I don't want, I want the whole screen to scroll.

Comment: For this you will have to remove your `BuildMainProfile` and the `Container` below it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226256/discussion-between-kanwar-manraj-and-dm-tr).

Answer (score 0):

```
PageView(
        children: [HomeScreen(), XodimlarScreen(), SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: DavomatScreen()),HomeScreen(),],
        controller: _pageControllerrr,

       // physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        onPageChanged: (page) {

            index = page;

        },
      ),
```

Comment: Might you please [edit] your answer to add some explanation why this code works?  As explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712), in the long term your answer will be useful to more people with with some explanation of when to use your code, and why it works.  Thanks!